# What does it mean that the three-body problem has been proved to be "unsolvable" and how was it done?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem) says:

> In 1887, mathematicians Heinrich Bruns and Henri Poincaré showed that there is no general analytical solution for the three-body problem given by algebraic expressions and integrals. The motion of three bodies is generally non-repeating, except in special cases.

I have two questions:

- What does an "analytical solution" mean here -- analytic in the sense of an [analytic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function)? Or in the sense of being built out of elementary functions?
- At a high level, how does the proof go? How does one rule out the existence of a solution like this?

[As a sidebar: is there a mathematical connection between Wikipedia's second sentence ("generally non-repeating") and its first? I can certainly imagine non-repeating solutions which are analytical. Are repeating solutions necessarily analytical?]

Comment: I know nothing about this, but the paper "The solution of the $n$-body problem" by Diacu contains the following paragraphs: "In his prize paper he [Poincaré] proved an even stronger theorem: there are no integrals---algebraic with respect to the time, the position, and the velocities only---other than the 10 known ones. [...]

Comment: In other words, these negative results showed it is impossible to solve the equations of motion of the $n$-body problem by reducing the dimension of the system with the help of first integrals. 
This does not mean that the $n$-body problem is unsolvable, just that a certain method fails to solve it. In fact, standard results of differential equations theory show that any initial value problem for the equations, with initial data not starting from collisions, leads to the existence of a unique solution defined on a maximal interval, which is the whole real line if singularities do not occur.

Comment: So the problem posed by King Oscar's prize made sense and could be solved, in principle. Unfortunately, the folk-mathematical tradition retained only one aspect of these results and perpetuated the wrong message that the $n$-body problem was unsolvable." So what Poincaré proved is that one cannot give a solution to the differential equations using integrals (and this seems to be the only description of what "analytic" means here).

Comment: [This](http://math.arizona.edu/~dwang/history/Kings-problem.pdf) might be of interest for you. In Russia Poincaré's conclusions about 3-body and $n$-body problem is usually attributed to homoclinic tangle which prevents having enough first integral to consider system fully integrable.

Comment: @zarathustra why not put this as an answer? Otherwise the question looks as if it's unanswered.